# Difference between $foo[bar] and $foo['bar'] in php

Tags: php, arrays, constants

I've been using `$foo[bar]` on a lot of project without noticing the missing '

Nowadays, I understand why it works, I assume it is because of a missing constant being replaced by it's name, thus referring to exactly the same array item.

But.. Is it very wrong or can it be accepted. What are the downsides? Should I dig in old projects to replace this or is the performance drop on this really not noticeable?

Comment: It is very wrong. It generates warnings, but the worst part is that you might, at some point, have a constant `define('bar', 'lorem ipsum')` and imagine what might happen in that case. As for performance drop, that's a deep topic. If you log warnings/errors, you'll increase I/O load on your hdd, if you log to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the downsides?

Say you have a URL like `http://somesite.com/test.php?item=20` ,

### Scenario:1 (Your case)

```
<?php
echo $_GET[item]; // 20 is printed with a warning..
```

### Scenario:2 (The worst case)

```
<?php
define('item',20);
echo $_GET[item]; // A warning will be thrown and nothing will be printed.
```

---

> Should I dig in old projects to replace this or is the performance
>   drop on this really not noticeable?

### I recommend you do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have turned on your error displaying then you can find notices like

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar' in [...][...]
>   on line

this if you used it like `$foo[bar]`

You can see the difference if execute the following code

```
$arr1 = array(1=>1);
$arr2 = array(a=>2);
$arr3 = array('a'=>3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

But its recomnded to use it with single quotes if the key of your array is a string because warnings will cause performance drop..

Answer (score 2):

in `$foo[bar]` `bar` must be constant and in $foo['bar'] `bar`  is key

if you use

```
$foo[bar] = "a";
```

you will get a notice like this

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar' in [some_path] on line 5
```

notice show that `bar` is not defined as constant so

decare `bar`  as constant first like this

```
define("bar", 10);
$foo[bar] = "a";
echo $foo[bar]; // will display 10
```

Comment: I think your last example is wrong, Or is it me? If you define bar as int 10, then the last line will look for the index 10 of array $foo, returning nothing in this case... no?